80's zombie movie in which the first zombie comes out of TV screen
I saw this movie in 1992. Color, English.
I only remember the part in which a woman is watching a documentary or a movie about a group of people going inside a cave. 
One of them gets injured and bleeds, accidentally spelling blood into the mouth of a a corpse. It comes back to life and attacks them. 
Can't remember what happened to them. But I can remember, the creature looks into the camera and walks towards it. Then he exits the screen to the room where the woman is sitting. 
He attacks her turning her into a zombie. Then everyone she attacks turns into a zombie. 
What I described is only the first act of the movie. I can't tell how it ends.

Technically, they're not really zombies. You're describing Demons 2 from 1986.

The film opens as if the events of the first film took place in reality, but this is actually a film within a film, that the various residents of a high-rise apartment building are watching. Its story follows several teens trespass into a city that was deserted as a result of the outbreak. Finding the lifeless corpse of a demon, one of the teens revives it accidentally by dripping blood from a scratch into its mouth.
In reality, frustrated party girl Sally Day (Coralina Cataldi-Tassoni) locks herself in her bedroom when her boyfriend doesn't attend her 16th birthday party. As her friends try to persuade her to return to the party, she watches part of the film on television. Suddenly, the demon notices her, climbs through the television and attacks her. Sally is transformed into a demon, then attacks her friends, turning all but two of them into vile, bloodthirsty monsters.

It was produced and co-written by Dario Argento and his daughter Asia appears there in her first role. The sequel to Demons from 1985. Here's the trailer:




Dead video link
